# Font loading error when using the ShoutemUI/TextInput component in a Exponent react-native framework

Tags: react-native, exponentjs, shoutem

I'm trying to use shoutem/ui with exponent and I’m getting an error using the shoutem/ui textinput component, where I get the following error message `fontFamily Rubik is not a system font and has not been loaded through Exponent.Font.loadAsync`

However I loaded all the custom shoutem fonts that were listed in the blog post https://blog.getexponent.com/using-react-native-ui-toolkits-with-exponent-3993434caf66#.iyiwjpwgu

Using the Exponent.Font.loadAsync method.

```
 fonts: [
          FontAwesome.font,
          {'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-Black': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Black.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-BlackItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-BlackItalic.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-Bold': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Bold.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-BoldItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-BoldItalic.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-Italic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Italic.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-Light': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Light.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-LightItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-LightItalic.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-Medium': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-MediumItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-MediumItalic.ttf')},
          {'Rubik-Regular': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf')},
          {'rubicon-icon-font': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/rubicon-icon-font.ttf')},
        ],
      });
```

Looking through the code I couldn't find the obvious fix - had trouble even finding where the style was set to throw the error.

Comment: What are those `@` on the paths for?

Comment: I see now. What a weird name for a package.

Comment: @Eldelshell, those are scoped npm packages, so people know what is developed officially by Shoutem: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code above seem to be missing one line. Try adding this line to the array list:

```
{'Rubik': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf')}
```

Comment: Yes, this fixed all issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code from the link

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Font, AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { View, Examples } from '@shoutem/ui';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fontsAreLoaded: false,
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'Rubik': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Black': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Black.ttf'),
      'Rubik-BlackItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-BlackItalic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Bold': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Bold.ttf'),
      'Rubik-BoldItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-BoldItalic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Italic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Italic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Light': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Light.ttf'),
      'Rubik-LightItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-LightItalic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Medium': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf'),
      'Rubik-MediumItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-MediumItalic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Regular': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf'),
      'rubicon-icon-font': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/rubicon-icon-font.ttf'),
    });

    this.setState({ fontsAreLoaded: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.fontsAreLoaded) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }

    return (
      <View styleName="flexible">
        <Examples />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" hidden={false} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```